# Problem with stretched value and classified value in ARCGIS desktop? They are different than each other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, symbology

I want to classify the value of an image into 3 groups. when I check properties of a raster image, stretched value is different than classified value. Here I have uploaded the images as follow.
[image: first fig is the stretched value of an raster image]

[image: Second one is the classified value of the same raster image]

I have no idea where this problem comes. Why they are different? How to fix them?

Comment: Is this a single band raster?

Comment: Yes, this figures come from the sam single band raster.